# Getting Down to the Nitty Gritty

Tags: rebus

How about this easy one?

(*I have to type 30 characters in the body even though my puzzle is composed of an image that says everything.*)

[image]

Comment: aaawwwwww!  Somebody didn't like it!

Comment: I don't think that was really necessary, but this is a bit on the trivial side

Comment: I liked it, don't worry ;).

Comment: Oh, I don't mind, really.  The crowd here tends to be finicky.  You are right though about it being trivial.  Haha I've got two questions at -11 and one at +21!  And my panda bear question has been as low as -13 (current -3).  I know a good 50 votes have been cast on just that one!

Comment: I wish this could be styled text instead of an image.

Comment: It still wouldn't add up to 30 characters; and I couldn't style it in that font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> Splitting hairs, since the word "hairs" is split with a pipe.

Comment: You guys are fast!  I'll have to think of harder ones.

Comment: @BGM How about [this](http://jamesgang.com/campfire/gifs/hare.gif) or [this](https://img.society6.com/cdn/box_006/post_16/930495_8823637_lz.jpg) or [this](http://www.freakingnews.com/pictures/115500/Splitting-Hairs-115942.jpg) or [this](http://rlv.zcache.ca/splitting_hares_mug-r15ca0b22717c48a29f811377d1e79de5_x7jgr_8byvr_324.jpg)

Comment: Oh my! Aren't we the violent type!  You should see the doctor about that!